# Import Velocity from webpack in Vuejs file

Tags: import, vuejs2, velocity.js

I'm new on vue.js and i've got .vue files. In one of these I want to use a Velocity transition but i'm unable to do this from webpack. Any idea to help me please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to include it in your `package.json` by running `npm install velocity-animate` in your app root. then import it in your component like this `import velocity from 'velocity-animate'` then you can use velocity object as you like.